# Remove DIV using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have a **div** with a button inside:

```
<div>
  <button id='delete_btn'>delete</button>
</div>
```

What would be the jQuery code to delete that **div** and ONLY that **div**
As I have another button that dynamically adds copies of that sample code above.

So I could have something like this, but I only want the **div** that contains the button pressed, to be deleted.

```
<div>
  <button id='delete_btn'>delete</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button id='delete_btn'>delete</button> 
</div>
```

thanks!

Comment: `id` should be unique.

Comment: When you say *only the div that contains the button* means that you wanna keep the button?

Comment: The whole lot, div and everything inside.

Answer (score 4):

`id` should not be duplicate in a document. Use class instead. Inside the click handler function, you can target the parent of `this` element to remove:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete_btn', function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button class='delete_btn'>delete</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button class='delete_btn'>delete</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was close, I tried $(this).parent.remove(); missing a (), and obviously i used id's instead of classes. Thanks!

Comment: I have another issue however. The div are being created when I push a button. I use jquery .append to add these to another div. The divs created dynamically do not delete when i push the button, only if the div is already written in the html.

Comment: @JohnHKawolski, to delete the dynamically created element you have use `.on()`....I have updated the code to work with dynamically created element.....please check.....thanks.

Comment: @JohnHKawolski don't use IDs, use classes

Comment: Thanks again! the new code works perfectly. I learned something too!

Comment: @JohnHKawolski, that's really grate to know:)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be performed with Vanilla JS and the newer `remove()` method.  If IE-support is not a necessity, consider the following; or, if IE-support is needed, it wouldn't take much to amend the following:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.delete_btn'))
    e.target.parentNode.remove()
}, false);
```

```html
<div>
  <button class='delete_btn'>delete 1</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button class='delete_btn'>delete 2</button>
</div>
```

#### event / state

This binds an event to the document (ancestor of the button).  The benefit from this is that the click handler will be called for any new delete buttons that are dynamically created after the page has loaded (and will still function).

#### class vs id

This also uses *class* in place of *id*.  This is because *id* should be reserved for unique values and *class* is intended to be a handle to like-elements.  JavaScript can produce unexpected behavior if multiple elements are named with the same ID.

#### remove()

Using `remove()` an element can be removed from the DOM as expected.  An older method would be to call the `removeChild()` on the parent (e.g., `parent=e.target.parentNode; parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent)`)

#### more ES6

Of course, you could simplify the code using a named-argument/destructuring-assignment, which essentially assigns `event.target` to a variables named `btn` and  The code can further be reduced, using a common arrow function.  See below.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({target: btn})=>{
  btn.matches('.delete_btn') && btn.parentNode.remove()
}, false);
```

```html
<div><button class='delete_btn'>delete 1</button></div>
<div><button class='delete_btn'>delete 2</button></div>
```

`{target: btn}` plucks the event argument being passed into the function and takes the value of the `target` property and assigns it to a new variable called `btn`.  If you just had `{target}` (without the assignment), in the function body you would replace `btn` with `target` (e.g., `target.matches(…)`, `target.parentNode`)

Comment: Awesome! thanks for this indepth answer, going to try both this method and the jquery method.